# URLConnection inputStream returns "Busy" why?

Tags: java

I've a method like this one below, but the problem is that this method returns busy instead OK. Any ideas how could I make this code working as it should. I am not sure why it returns the busy I've also tried to change the URLConnection to HttpURLConnection and close the inputstream and the connection in the finally block but it does not bring any positive results.

```
public static final byte[] BYTES_READER = new byte[4096];

public String connect(String addressUrl) {
InputStream is = null;
URL url = null;
URLConnection connection = null;

try {
 url = new URL(addressUrl);
 urlc = url.openConnection();
 urlc.setDoOutput(true);
 is = urlc.getInputStream();
 int output = is.read(BYTES_READER);
 if (output > 0) {
  return new String(BYTES_READER, 0, output);
 }
 is.close();

return null;
}
catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: So the string returned is "BUSY" instead of the "OK" status? If so, that's coming from the HTTP server, not your code. You can use the `curl` command to confirm. BTW, using the a static `BYTES_READER` array as a buffer makes your code not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

How about check response code before read out data from stream. And maybe use a string buffer to append the data.